# Ant JavaDoc task throwing `NoClassDefFoundError` from within a custom taglet, even though the class *is* on the classpath

Tags: java, ant, classpath, javadoc, taglet

I am having trouble with a JavaDoc Ant task. It's giving me a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` for a class that, as far as I can tell, is definitely on the classpath. According to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html), a `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown when the class existed during compilation, but can't be found during runtime. (A [`NoClassDefFoundError` is *not* a `ClassNotFoundException`](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/07/classnotfoundexception-vs.html).)

When I remove the classpath item, it fails as expected (lots of package/symbol not found errors) and it *still* gives the same `NoClassDefFoundError`. Why does this fail for the taglet whether the class is on the classpath or not?

---

The specifics:

The class it can't find is called `com.github.xbn.io.SimpleDebugable`, and it's in this jar file:

- Jar file: `C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\z_build\jar_dependencies\xbnjava-0.1.4.2-all.jar`

[image: screenshot]

The JavaDoc Ant task. The above jar file is the very first item in the classpath.

```
<target name="doca" description="Generates javadoc documentation.">
   <property name="jar_base_dir" value="C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\z_build\jar_dependencies\"/>
   <property name="taglet_jar" value="C:\data_jeffy\programming\build\codelet-0.1.4.1\download\codelet-0.1.4.1-all.jar"/>

   <javadoc
      packagenames="com.github.aliteralmind.codelet,com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.alter,com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.simplesig,com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet,com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.type,com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.util"
      defaultexcludes="yes"
      destdir="C:\data_jeffy\programming\build\codelet-0.1.4.1\documentation\javadoc"
      splitindex="true"
      additionalparam="-J-Dcodelet_config_dir=C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\codelet_config\"
      classpath="${jar_base_dir}xbnjava-0.1.4.2-all.jar;
      C:\data_jeffy\programming\build\codelet-0.1.4.1\download\codelet-0.1.4.1-all.jar;
      ${jar_base_dir}templatefeather-0.1.1.2-all.jar;
      ${jar_base_dir}commons-io-2.4.jar;
      ${jar_base_dir}guava-16.0.1.jar;
      ${jar_base_dir}jdk_751__tools__contains_com_sun.jar"
   >
      <sourcepath>
          <pathelement path="C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\src"/>
      </sourcepath>
      <!-- Custom taglets-->
         <taglet name="com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.CodeletTaglet"
            path="${taglet_jar}"/>
         <taglet name="com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.CodeletDotOutTaglet"
            path="${taglet_jar}"/>
         <taglet name="com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.CodeletAndOutTaglet"
            path="${taglet_jar}"/>
         <taglet name="com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.FileTextletTaglet"
            path="${taglet_jar}"/>
   </javadoc>
</target>
```

It results in this:

```
[javadoc] javadoc: error - In doclet class com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard,
method start has thrown an exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[javadoc] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/xbn/io/SimpleDebuggable
```

Full output:

```
[C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet]ant docx
Buildfile: C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\build.xml

docx:
  [javadoc] Generating Javadoc
  [javadoc] Javadoc execution
  [javadoc] Loading source files for package com.github.aliteralmind.codelet...
  [javadoc] Loading source files for package com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.alter...
  [javadoc] Loading source files for package com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.simplesig...
  [javadoc] Loading source files for package com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet...
  [javadoc] Loading source files for package com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.type...
  [javadoc] Loading source files for package com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.util...
  [javadoc] Constructing Javadoc information...
  [javadoc] 1 error
  [javadoc] javadoc: error - In doclet class com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard, method start has thrown an exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  [javadoc] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/xbn/io/SimpleDebuggable
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
  [javadoc]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
  [javadoc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
  [javadoc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
  [javadoc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
  [javadoc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
  [javadoc]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  [javadoc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
  [javadoc]     at com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.CodeletBootstrap.wasLoaded(Unknown Source)
  [javadoc]     at com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.CodeletBootstrap.loadConfiguration(Unknown Source)
  [javadoc]     at com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.CodeletBootstrap.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
  [javadoc]     at com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.CodeletTaglet.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.taglets.TagletManager.addCustomTag(TagletManager.java:219)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.Configuration.initTagletManager(Configuration.java:466)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.Configuration.setOptions(Configuration.java:437)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.Configuration.setOptions(Configuration.java:447)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.startGeneration(AbstractDoclet.java:120)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.start(AbstractDoclet.java:83)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.start(HtmlDoclet.java:63)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.start(Standard.java:39)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:280)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:160)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:397)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:167)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:49)
  [javadoc] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.xbn.io.SimpleDebuggable
  [javadoc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
  [javadoc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
  [javadoc]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  [javadoc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
  [javadoc]     ... 37 more

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

When you completely remove the jar file from the classpath, it fails as expected, with a few hundred `package com.github.xbn.... does not exist` and `symbol not found` errors, meaning the classpath element is clearly "working". So why isn't it working for the taglet?

The output with the jar *not* on the classpath:

```
[C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet]ant docx
Buildfile: C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\build.xml

docx:
  [javadoc] Generating Javadoc
  [javadoc] Javadoc execution
  [javadoc] Loading source files for package com.github.aliteralmind.codelet...
  [javadoc] Loading source files for package com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.alter...
  [javadoc] Loading source files for package com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.simplesig...
  [javadoc] Loading source files for package com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet...
  [javadoc] Loading source files for package com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.type...
  [javadoc] Loading source files for package com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.util...
  [javadoc] Constructing Javadoc information...
  [javadoc] C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\src\com\github\aliteralmind\codelet\BasicCustomizers.java:18: error: package com.github.xbn.linefilter.alter does not exist

  [javadoc]     import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.alter.TextLineAlterer;
  [javadoc]                                            ^
  [javadoc] C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\src\com\github\aliteralmind\codelet\BasicCustomizers.java:19: error: package com.github.xbn.linefilter does not exist
  [javadoc]     import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.FilteredLineIterator;
  [javadoc]                                      ^
  [javadoc] C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\src\com\github\aliteralmind\codelet\BasicCustomizers.java:20: error: package com.github.xbn.analyze.alter does not exist
  [javadoc]     import  com.github.xbn.analyze.alter.ExpirableElements;
  [javadoc]                                         ^
  [javadoc] C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\src\com\github\aliteralmind\codelet\BasicCustomizers.java:21: error: package com.github.xbn.analyze.alter does not exist
  [javadoc]     import  com.github.xbn.analyze.alter.MultiAlterType;
  [javadoc]                                         ^
  [javadoc] C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\src\com\github\aliteralmind\codelet\BasicCustomizers.java:22: error: package com.github.xbn.array does not exist
  [javadoc]     import  com.github.xbn.array.NullElement;
  [javadoc]                                 ^
  [javadoc] C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\src\com\github\aliteralmind\codelet\BasicCustomizers.java:23: error: package com.github.xbn.lang does not exist
  [javadoc]     import  com.github.xbn.lang.IllegalArgumentStateException;
  [javadoc]                                ^
```

Continued (~1,500 lines removed):

```
  [javadoc]     import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.FilteredLineIterator;
  [javadoc]                                      ^
  [javadoc] C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\src\com\github\aliteralmind\codelet\util\zCodeletCustomizers.java:25: error: package com.github.xbn.analyze.alter does notexist
  [javadoc]     import  com.github.xbn.analyze.alter.ExpirableElements;
  [javadoc]                                         ^
  [javadoc] C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\src\com\github\aliteralmind\codelet\util\zCodeletCustomizers.java:26: error: package com.github.xbn.analyze.alter does notexist
  [javadoc]     import  com.github.xbn.analyze.alter.MultiAlterType;
  [javadoc]                                         ^
  [javadoc] C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\src\com\github\aliteralmind\codelet\util\zCodeletCustomizers.java:27: error: package com.github.xbn.array does not exist
  [javadoc] 1 error
  [javadoc]     import  com.github.xbn.array.NullElement;
  [javadoc] 371 warnings
  [javadoc]                                 ^
```

Continued: Here at the very end, it gives the same error as it did when the jar *was* in the classpath:

```
  [javadoc] javadoc: error - In doclet class com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard,
  method start has thrown an exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  [javadoc] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/xbn/io/SimpleDebuggable
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
  [javadoc]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
  [javadoc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
  [javadoc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
  [javadoc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
  [javadoc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
  [javadoc]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  [javadoc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
  [javadoc]     at com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.CodeletBootstrap.wasLoaded(Unknown Source)
  [javadoc]     at com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.CodeletBootstrap.loadConfiguration(Unknown Source)
  [javadoc]     at com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.CodeletBootstrap.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
  [javadoc]     at com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.CodeletTaglet.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.taglets.TagletManager.addCustomTag(TagletManager.java:219)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.Configuration.initTagletManager(Configuration.java:466)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.Configuration.setOptions(Configuration.java:437)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.Configuration.setOptions(Configuration.java:447)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.startGeneration(AbstractDoclet.java:120)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.start(AbstractDoclet.java:83)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.start(HtmlDoclet.java:63)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.start(Standard.java:39)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:280)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:160)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:397)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:167)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:49)
  [javadoc] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.xbn.io.SimpleDebuggable
  [javadoc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
  [javadoc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
  [javadoc]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  [javadoc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
  [javadoc]     ... 37 more

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

---

In the original (above) target, the taglet's paths are pointing to the jar file. For the below,I've extracted the taglet class files out of the jar and into a directory (only these four taglet classes are extracted, everything else remains in the jar), and changed the taglet paths to the root directory.

```
<property name="jar_base_dir" value="C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\z_build\jar_dependencies\"/>
<property name="taglet_base_dir" value="C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\bin\com\github\aliteralmind\codelet\taglet"/>
  <javadoc
  packagenames="com.github.aliteralmind.codelet,com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.alter,com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.simplesig,com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet,com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.type,com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.util"
  defaultexcludes="yes"
  destdir="C:\data_jeffy\programming\build\codelet-0.1.4.1\documentation\javadoc"
  splitindex="true"
  additionalparam="-J-Dcodelet_config_dir=${dir_sandbox}${codelet.config.dir}${fs}"
  classpath="${jar_base_dir}xbnjava-0.1.4.2-all.jar;
  C:\data_jeffy\programming\build\codelet-0.1.4.1\download\codelet-0.1.4.1-all.jar;
  ${jar_base_dir}templatefeather-0.1.1.2-all.jar;
  ${jar_base_dir}commons-io-2.4.jar;
  ${jar_base_dir}guava-16.0.1.jar;
  ${jar_base_dir}jdk_751__tools__contains_com_sun.jar"
>
  <sourcepath>
    <pathelement path="C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\src"/>
  </sourcepath>
  <!-- Custom taglets-->
    <taglet name="com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.CodeletTaglet"
      path="${taglet_base_dir}"/>
    <taglet name="com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.CodeletDotOutTaglet"
      path="${taglet_base_dir}"/>
    <taglet name="com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.CodeletAndOutTaglet"
      path="${taglet_base_dir}"/>
    <taglet name="com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.FileTextletTaglet"
      path="${taglet_base_dir}"/>
</javadoc>
```

And now the `NoClassDefFoundError` doesn't happen. Instead it's

```
javadoc: error - Error - Exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
thrown while trying to register Taglet com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.CodeletTaglet...
```

Now the problem is, it seems that this error is being "swallowed" by JavaDoc. I don't know how to see the trace of that `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

Full output:

```
docb:
  [javadoc] Generating Javadoc
  [javadoc] Javadoc execution
  [javadoc] Loading source files for package com.github.aliteralmind.codelet...
  [javadoc] Loading source files for package com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.alter...
  [javadoc] Loading source files for package com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.simplesig...
  [javadoc] Loading source files for package com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet...
  [javadoc] Loading source files for package com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.type...
  [javadoc] Loading source files for package com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.util...
  [javadoc] Constructing Javadoc information...
  [javadoc] javadoc: error - Error - Exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
  thrown while trying to register Taglet com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.CodeletTaglet...
  [javadoc] javadoc: error - Error - Exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
  thrown while trying to register Taglet com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.CodeletDotOutTaglet...
  [javadoc] javadoc: error - Error - Exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
  thrown while trying to register Taglet com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.CodeletAndOutTaglet...
  [javadoc] Standard Doclet version 1.7.0_72
  [javadoc] javadoc: error - Error - Exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException thrown while trying to register Taglet com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.FileTextletTaglet...
  [javadoc] Building tree for all the packages and classes...
  [javadoc] C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\src\com\github\aliteralmind\codelet\BasicCustomizers.java:90:
  warning - @.codelet is an unknown tag.

  ...lots of lines deleted...

  [javadoc] C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\src\com\github\aliteralmind\codelet\util\JavaDocUtil.java:185:
  warning - @.codelet.and.out is an unknown tag.
  [javadoc] C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\src\com\github\aliteralmind\codelet\util\JavaDocUtil.java:185:
  warning - @.codelet.and.out is an unknown tag.
  [javadoc] Building index for all the packages and classes...
  [javadoc] Building index for all classes...
  [javadoc] Generating C:\data_jeffy\programming\build\codelet-0.1.4.1\documentation\javadoc\help-doc.html...
  [javadoc] 4 errors
  [javadoc] 57 warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
```

And again with verbose output: http://dpaste.com/3T0B40X

Comment: Did you build this particular Jar yourself? Is it possible that this class file was corrupted or compiled for a different (newer) java version? Try a clean build of the jar.

Comment: @geert3 The code is compiled and jar-ed immediately before the javadoc target is called, every time. I don't know if this matters, but here are the two Ant environment variables: `ANT_HOME=C:\applications\programming\java\apache-ant-1.9.4`, `JAVA_HOME=C:\applications\programming\java\jdk_1p7p0_72`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the taglet path. The classpath must be redundantly passed into both the main JavaDoc task, and each of the custom taglets. The taglets must each have different `ClassLoader`s, and therefore require the duplicated classpath.

The ant [documentation for the taglet's "path" attribute](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html#tagletelement) does not explicitly say that this is a classpath, and that's what confused me:

> *A path specifying the search path for the taglet class (e.g. /home/taglets). The path may also be specified by a nested  element*

The working target:

```
<target name="docc" description="Generates javadoc documentation.">

   <property name="jar_base_dir" value="C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\z_build\jar_dependencies\"/>
   <property name="taglet_base_dir" value="C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\bin\"/>
   <property name="javadoc_classpath"
      value="${jar_base_dir}xbnjava-0.1.4.2-all.jar;C:\data_jeffy\programming\build\codelet-0.1.4.1\download\codelet-0.1.4.1-all.jar;${jar_base_dir}templatefeather-0.1.1.2-all.jar;${jar_base_dir}commons-io-2.4.jar;${jar_base_dir}guava-16.0.1.jar;${jar_base_dir}jdk_751__tools__contains_com_sun.jar;${jar_base_dir}commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar"/>

   <javadoc
      packagenames="com.github.aliteralmind.codelet,com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.alter,com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.simplesig,com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet,com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.type,com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.util"
      defaultexcludes="yes"
      destdir="C:\data_jeffy\programming\build\codelet-0.1.4.1\documentation\javadoc"
      splitindex="true"
      additionalparam="-J-Dcodelet_config_dir=${dir_sandbox}${codelet.config.dir}${fs}"
      classpath="${javadoc_classpath}"
   >
      <sourcepath>
         <pathelement path="C:\data_jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\codelet\src"/>
      </sourcepath>
      <!-- Custom taglets-->
         <taglet name="com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.CodeletTaglet"
            path="${javadoc_classpath}"/>
         <taglet name="com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.CodeletDotOutTaglet"
            path="${javadoc_classpath}"/>
         <taglet name="com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.CodeletAndOutTaglet"
            path="${javadoc_classpath}"/>
         <taglet name="com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.FileTextletTaglet"
            path="${javadoc_classpath}"/>
   </javadoc>
</target>
```

An more-portable alternative:

```
<target name="docd" description="Generates javadoc documentation.">
   <property name="sandbox_grandparent" value="C:/data_jeffy/programming/"/>
   <property name="sandbox_parent" value="${sandbox_grandparent}sandbox/z__for_git_commit_only/"/>
   <property name="sandbox" value="${sandbox_parent}codelet/"/>

   <path id="project_classpath2">
      <pathelement location="${sandbox_parent}codelet/bin/"/>
      <pathelement location="${sandbox_grandparent}/build/codelet-0.1.4.1/download/codelet-0.1.4.1-all.jar"/>
      <fileset dir="${sandbox}z_build/jar_dependencies/" includes="*.jar"/>
   </path>
   <pathconvert pathsep=";" property="javadoc_classpath" refid="project_classpath2"/>

   <javadoc
      packagenames="com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.*"
      defaultexcludes="yes"
      destdir="${sandbox_grandparent}/build/codelet-0.1.4.1/documentation/javadoc"
      splitindex="true"
      additionalparam="-J-Dcodelet_config_dir=${dir_sandbox}${codelet.config.dir}${fs}"
      classpathref="project_classpath2"
   >
      <sourcepath>
         <pathelement path="${sandbox}src"/>
      </sourcepath>
      <!-- Custom taglets-->
         <taglet name="com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.CodeletTaglet"
            path="${javadoc_classpath}"/>
         <taglet name="com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.CodeletDotOutTaglet"
            path="${javadoc_classpath}"/>
         <taglet name="com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.CodeletAndOutTaglet"
            path="${javadoc_classpath}"/>
         <taglet name="com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.taglet.FileTextletTaglet"
            path="${javadoc_classpath}"/>
   </javadoc>
</target>
```